# How to find number of days in a year column?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Index":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   "Year":[2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024]})

df
Out[12]: 
   Index  Year
0      0  2019
1      1  2020
2      2  2021
3      3  2022
4      4  2023
5      5  2024
```

I would like to create a new column with the total number of days on that year. Could you help me?

I tried `df["Days"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Year"]).dt.days` but I got the following error:

AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'days'

The output should be:

```
   Index  Year Days
0      0  2019 365
1      1  2020 366
2      2  2021 365
3      3  2022 365
4      4  2023 365
5      5  2024 366
```

Comment: Check if it's leap year or no and base new column off of that.

Comment: I used 'df["Days"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Year"]).dt.is_leap_year ' and got all False values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Index":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   "Year":[2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024]})

df["Days"] = [pd.Timestamp(x, 12, 31).dayofyear for x in df.Year]

df
```

Output:

```
    Index   Year    Days
0   0   2019    365
1   1   2020    366
2   2   2021    365
3   3   2022    365
4   4   2023    365
5   5   2024    366
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the dates at the end of the year vs the start of the year

```
d = pd.to_datetime('1/1/'+df['Year'].astype(str))

df['Days'] = (d + pd.tseries.offsets.YearEnd(0) - d).dt.days.add(1)
```

or check for leap year:

```
df['Days'] = np.where(d.dt.is_leap_year,366,365)
```

Output:

```
   Index  Year  Date
0      0  2019   365
1      1  2020   366
2      2  2021   365
3      3  2022   365
4      4  2023   365
5      5  2024   366
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
import calendar

df = pd.DataFrame({"Index":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   "Year":[2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024]})

df['Days'] = df['Year'].map(lambda x: 365 + int(calendar.isleap(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`is_leap_year`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.is_leap_year.html):

```
df['Days'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], format='%Y').dt.is_leap_year.add(365)
```

Output:

```
   Index  Year  Days
0      0  2019   365
1      1  2020   366
2      2  2021   365
3      3  2022   365
4      4  2023   365
5      5  2024   366
```